# Is this Firebase Security Rule Enough for my Use Case?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I want to use the same data structure as the official Firebase sample as shown below. If I use the following Firebase Security Rule, is it secure enough? My goal is for each user to ONLY have access to the groups they belong to. BTW, I'm using email and pwd authentication

```
{
    "rules": {
        "users": {
            ".write": true,
            "$uid": {
                ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/web/org
[image]

Comment: `"auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"` check that a user is logged in (with any service) and that the current node name matches their `uid`. This security rule does nothing with groups, so: no, it is not enough to ensure that a user has access to the groups they belong to. Note that you can test your rules in the Simulator tab of your Firebase dashboard to try that out. It will not only tell you *whether* the read/write operation is allowed, but will also be specific about *why* it is/isn't allowed.

Comment: Does the rule structure has to match the data structure? Do you have a sample rule that will get me started?

Comment: I suggest you read the entire guide and try to understand the samples in there (the one you copied above is just from the quick start): https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/user-security.html. There is a great example in there, that is not too far off from what you're trying to do.If something is unclear, ask a question. Once you're done with the guide, try them out in your own Firebase application. And then try to modify them to your needs. Again, when having problems: ask a question about that specific problem.

Comment: Frank, thank you for the suggestion. I know my question was a little too broad. I will postulate a new, more direct, question.